# What is faster for radial location based search? Lucene or Sphinx?

Tags: codeigniter, lucene, sphinx

I'm part of a development team working on a job board, and we're considering both Lucene and Sphinx for out search base.

Does anyone have experience working with either of these open-source tools for location based search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene doesn't have any specialized support for spatial searches. It's an Information Retrieval system, not a GIS.

Answer (score 2):

True that Lucene doesn't have it built-in, but Solr (a search server built using Lucene) does. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/j-spatial/index.html) is an article that explains how.